# open source tools for AI

Tags: java, nlp

I'm through AI project which contain some methods that i have to apply in the project, the methods have some open source. but each method has different open source, i would like to have one open source and it's documentation which contain all the methods in it 
the methods are

```
Stemming 
extracting Stopwords
Latent Semantic Analysis LSA
K nearest neighbor KNN
Support Vector Machine SVM
```

Comment: In the general sense, I can think of no good reason why you cannot use "methods" from different libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools which are in able to do all these, [gate](http://gate.ac.uk/) is one of them as well as [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)